# Unable to load your default controller - given solution doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the same issue as [unable to load your default controller on Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686196/unable-to-load-your-default-controller-on-codeigniter).  I am trying to simply load my site, [tripmatcher.herokuapp.com](http://tripmatcher.herokuapp.com), and I get a 500 with that URL, and the **`'Unable to load your default controller'`** message when loading 
.

The home folder for me is application/front, and within that there is a folder called index.html.  This is defined as the home folder within `index.php` like so:

```
/*

 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = 'application/front';
```

I have also tried just specifying /index as the root, as well as home/index and home/index.html.  I am strugging to work out what it is I am doing wrong.

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you change the application folder path ?? It should be

```
$application_folder = 'application';
```

---

Assume your controller name is **`welcome`**. Then File name should be **`Welcome.php`**. And inside the file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

}
```

---

In routes (application/config/routes.php)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

Comment: So the welcome controller should be within the application folder itself, right?

Comment: sorry didn't get you

Comment: It should be in the `application/controllers` folder

Comment: At the moment it is application/controllers/welcome.php, is that the right place?

Comment: ya. Its  must. else CI will never know that has a Controller

Comment: That should do the trick hopefully, the thing is I've inherited this project from other developers and the folder structure is all messed up in general, so I will just move the controllers, views etc over to a different environment.

Comment: Follow the Naming conversion all the time https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @MichaelNares happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$application_folder = 'application'; /* or whatever you want */
```

Then when you want to configure the default controller you can edit `application/config/routes.php`

`$route['default_controller'] = 'default_controller'; /* where default controller is the controller what you want be the default */`